# How do you reformat an annotated date in Spring MVC when validation has failed?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a Spring-MVC app that is displaying a form based on a bean. The bean has a date field annotated with this:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE_TIME)
```

This works as expected; the date displays in that format. Meanwhile, other fields in the bean are being validated using JPA validation annotations. When the user submits the form, I have a custom data converter registered to convert the incoming String into a Date which appears to be running fine.

So the problem happens when the user submits the form and validation fails on one of the other fields. When the validation error sends the user back to the form input page, the format on the date has changed to what you'd expect after calling toString() on a date object.

Is there a way to re-trigger the DateTimeFormat annotation on the object before it is sent back to the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is wrong with your setup, you don't need a custom data converter to convert `String` into `Date`. If everything configured fine, `@DateTimeFormat` controls the data conversion in all cases, both incoming and outcoming.

Make sure you have `<mvc:annotation-driven />` and don't override default converters in some way.

Take a look at the samples, such as [mvc-showcase](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/07/22/spring-mvc-3-showcase/).

Comment: Thanks, that narrowed down the problem for me. I had set up the conversionService with a Factory that only did conversion, and not formatting. As soon as I changed it (and removed our custom converter), then it started working. Here's the conversionService bean I'm using now: <bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">.

Comment: @Travelsized: Yes, if you need custom converters, the recommended way to install them is to override `FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean.installFormatters()` (don't forget to call `super.installFormatters()`).